# Percentile calculation in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of two columns with the first column containing values and the second column containing the corresponding weight of those values. I need to be able to replicate calculation of weighted percentiles from a text source. So I came up with a solution that uses nested "for loops" to go through the dataframe, calculate all percentiles and save them in a dictionary (see the code between #---pct_calc_start and #---pct_calc_end).

I have verified that the calculated percentiles match the text so they are correct but this is not an efficient solution and takes a very long time to run on a large dataset. This is mostly due to the second "for loop" that iterates through the entire df for each p'th percentile calculation. Is it possible to use df.apply method to replicate this process?

The logic to compute the weighted percentiles are as follows:

```
W=sum(weights)
To calculate pth percentile with data and weight pairs [x1, w1], [x2, w2], [x3, w3]...

if w1 > p*W then pth_percentile = x1
if sum(w_j)__(j=1, i) = p*W then pth_percentile = 0.5*(x_i + x_[i+1])
if sum(w_j)__(j=1, i) < p*W then pth_percentile = x_[i+1]
```

I have included a small sample dataset with the code below but my original data set has 150,000 rows and the calculations are really slow.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time



x = [[221900,543.0423], [321900,543.0423], [538000,628.1226], [180000,101.2122], [604000,823.361], [510000,703.331],
    [1225000,53.2555], [257500,637.342], [291850,850.231], [229500,551.4356], [323000,785.1777], [662500,756.9911],
    [468000,215.5735], [310000,770.0425], [400000,623.4555], [530000,20.2496], [650000,653.0772], [395000,402.8929], 
    [485000,597.685], [189000,928.7065], [230000,806.2281], [385000,177.2296], [2000000,60.8927], [285000,187.9004], 
    [252700,323.3607], [329000,190.6385], [233000,901.0717], [937000,77.7488], [667000,515.2111], [438000,665.4766], 
    [719000,437.342]]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['price','num_homes'])

start_time = time.time()

# sort values in ascending order and add columns necessary to do the calculation 
df = df.sort_values(by='price', ascending=True)
weight_sum = df['num_homes'].sum()
df['cumulative_num_homes'] = df['num_homes'].cumsum()
df['price_next'] = df['price'].shift(-1)

# save pct in this dict
pctl_dict = {}

weight0 = df['num_homes'].iloc[0]
val0 = df['price'].iloc[0]

#---pct_calc_start
for p in range(0,101):
    p_weight_sum = 0.01 * p * weight_sum

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if weight0 > p_weight_sum:
            pctl = val0 

        elif row['cumulative_num_homes'] == p_weight_sum:
            pctl = 0.5*(row['price']+row['price_next'])

        elif row['cumulative_num_homes'] < p_weight_sum:
            pctl =row['price_next']

    if p==100:
        pctl = df['price'].iloc[-1]

    pctl_dict[p] = pctl
#---pct_calc_end

end_time = time.time()

print("runtime:", round(end_time-start_time,4),"\n")

# print pct
for key, value in pctl_dict.items():
    print("pctl_"+str(key)+":  ",value)
```

Here is the output (truncated at 11th percentile)

```
runtime: 0.2199 

pctl_0:   180000
pctl_1:   189000.0
pctl_2:   189000.0
pctl_3:   189000.0
pctl_4:   189000.0
pctl_5:   189000.0
pctl_6:   189000.0
pctl_7:   221900.0
pctl_8:   221900.0
pctl_9:   221900.0
pctl_10:   221900.0
pctl_11:   229500.0
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind calculating weighted percentiles?

Comment: I added brief logic in my question above.